# Mysql performance between-and vs limit

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I'm wondering about potential performance problems on a query I'm writing.  There are more than enough posts about between/and sometimes being slow, and also limit being slow.  The column I need to reference always has sequential numbers in it, so it is possible for me to use either style.

my table:

```
pkey INT, idcol INT, rank INT, datafields....
```

There is an index on (idcol, rank).  Rank is always sequential starting from 0.  It is not possible for there to be a gap in it (or else something is broken).  Thus, I have the following 2 options to get data:

Option 1:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE idcol = 1 AND rank BETWEEN 12 AND 15 ORDER BY rank;
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE idcol = 1 AND rank >= 12 ORDER BY rank LIMIT 4;
```

I would guess option 1 is best but I'm not sure ... is it faster to just find '12' in the index and then get the next 3 rows without having to keep comparing rank <= 15?

Comment: IMOHO, they are "the same" unless there is a *performance profile* to show otherwise (because this is ultimately what the question is about, the *execution time* of particular queries against a implementation/schema): both should benefit from the same indices, at least theoretically.

Comment: Try adding `EXPLAIN` to your statement. MySQL itself can likely answer that for you.

Comment: Oddly, I'd forgotten all about explain - maybe a good sign to stop working and start drinking since it is new year's eve.  IMHO too, I had thought that performance differences would only in the millisecond range - but I expect this query to run millions of times (maybe even per day).  Explain surprised me - it's not even close - option 1 says it will look at 4 rows, option 2 will look at 38 rows (rank currently goes from 0-49 for each idcol in my dev db, so I guess the 38 is looking from 12->max).

Comment: @Inukshuk It really ought not to matter for such small numbers (although it is slightly interesting that the plans are different anyway). Write maintainable code/queries/schema first. Then, when there actually *is* a problem, tackle it.

Comment: That was my inner debate ... intuitively, it makes more sense to me to write start at x, and return y results.  But from db perspective I thought it might be (and apparently is) a lot better to say between x and (x + y - 1).

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is what I would use: it is more robust for later changes.

Speed? Try `explain` to let MySQL explain its execution strategy. Try massive dummy  data and measure. In fact I think optimization irrelevant here. Besides the index, which is to the point.

More likely this query occurs together with simmilar isolated queries, maybe inside a larger query. *There* would be potential to let the database do a larger portion.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine their speeds will be fairly close to the same thing. What may be a bigger factor is how you want it to respond when something IS broken.

Do you want all rows between some start and some stop and it potentially could be missing a few? Or do you want exactly 4 rows, the first being at a particular primary key value and it may go passed your expected end value?

Performance is one thing but what might save you from bigger problems in the future might be error handling. If I were you, I'd use `between-and`.

Comment: Sometimes responding to something broken is more important than speed.

Comment: The question kind of dead ended in that they're fairly equal queries. After that, I felt error handling was the next factor to consider. Nobody likes to admit that it'll happen but it's better to be proactive instead of reactive to problems.

Comment: Indeed, it did. Without plans or numbers it's a very poor question :(

Comment: No gaps possible ... think of it like looking for the 12-15th ranked tennis players in the world - not possible for #14 to be missing there, so either method would work.  As added above, this could run millions of times (and on a relatively large db too) - I was thinking any performance improvement could be beneficial.

Comment: @lnukshuk And I'm glad to see you found one. I would have expected `limit` to prevent the query from looking at as many as it did.